# Limited connection with Windows 8.1

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, dns, proxy

My PC is running Windows 8.1 Pro.

I'd been having problems for a while with my wireless network at home, so i decided to buy a new router. The router is the DSL-N55U from Asus.

This router was working great with every device i have(Notebook, iPad, cellphone etc) but my desktop PC.

The problem started back when i had the old router and it was a stability problem, the connection would stay up only for a few minutes or so, then it'd become limited and Troubleshooting would give you the "DNS server not responding" answer.

With the new router the problem persisted, kinda.
The gaps between one fall and the other were noticeably larger and it wouldn't give me the "Limited Connection" warning, it'd just stop working.

But after only 2 days with the new router my PC's wireless connection stopped working completely. Now it's always limited and troubleshooting gives me another error: "Windows couldn't automatically detect this network's proxy settings".

I tried every solution online, restore modem to factory settings, **netsh winsock(ipv4/v6 etc) reset** doesn't work, already tried the registry trick to make netsh reset work in win 8.1 but none would make my connection work. So i attempted the last solution which was to replace the adapter.

I bought a Asus N13 N300, but the problem persisted, updated the driver, problem persists.

I'm completely out of ideas.

EDIT: I noticed something new, although my average wireless signal is of two bars, this non-working connection goes up to 5 bars! And that's not even the weirder part, because at first it could be the new router and adapter etc... But running the Asus wireless scanner utility, the signal is of 1 bar 2 bar max. So i went to the wireless properties again and it's showing a 1Mbps of effective signal strength speed with no access to internet(which is really slow since it should be 54Mbps minimum).

EDIT 2: See answer...

[image: ipconfig all print]

Answer (score 0):

You can check the proxy settings that are under "Internet Settings" to check if you have configured a proxy per error. Cancel the settings, only check the first check box Automatic...

[image]

Comment: There were no proxies, i checked in both lan settings and adapter settings

Comment: than go to static IP configuration. Set you ip statically and the DNS to a verified DNS like google 8.8.8.8 ore 4.2.2.2

Comment: i've tried changing dns before, will try setting my ip statically and post results, thanks!

Comment: Nothing changes with static IP, can you check my EDIT and see if it means anything?

Comment: Have you entered a valid ip subnet and router ip? You could try getting the router or pc closer to each other and see if is any difference

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem with windows:  It apparently has a bug saying the connection is at full strength when it's actually just at 2 bars and i don't know how to fix that unfortunately.

Problem was wifi range, somehow i managed to get the adapter a little closer to the router and now it's working(although really slow).

Solution for people who might get this same problem: buy a powerline adapter(My option) or a Wifi Extender.